# Why does adding polygon in QGIS sometimes create a feature with edge too far across the screen? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: qgis, error, digitizing

While digiting/creating new polygons in QGIS some polygons have elongated edges. Some features have no geometry (area=zero) too. What could be the reason?  I use 3 Monitors, one for QGIS, one for GoogleEarth and one of Laptop. The version of QGIS is 2.18.11

[image: The image shows two polygons creaded using add-feature tool in qgis. The straight line accross left side of screen appeared after saving the layer. Then some features have null in geometry as well.]

Comment: May I ask you, do you work with two monitors?

Comment: One of those features looks like it has edges that cross each other. When that happens, the feature has no inside, so an area calculation will return an error or 0.

Comment: What version of QGIS?

Comment: @TarasDubrava Yes, I use 3 Monitors, one for QGIS, one for GoogleEarth and one of Laptop.

Comment: @csk Qgis Version 2.18.11

Comment: [@Ram Shrestha](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/72812/ram-shrestha), I would not blame QGIS but I would blame the multimonitor activity. Since when you switch between GoogleEarth and QGIS, the node of the editing polygon goes together with your mouse to the screen with GoogleEarth.

Comment: @TarasDubrava Okay

Comment: When someone request more information, please **edit your question** to include that information.

Comment: I believe that you may have problems with the original geo-data ...